# Swift/Xcode AdColony returns error when trying to call AdColony.configure in appdelegate

Tags: swift, video, xcode6, appdelegate, adcolony

im trying to initialize AdColony in my appdelegate with this line of code:

```
AdColony.configureWithAppID(appID: "app id", zoneIDs: ["zoneid1", "zoneid2"], delegate: self, logging: true)
```

however, I getting this error:

> Cannot invoke 'configureWithAppID' with an argument list of type '(appID: String, zoneIDs: [String], delegate: AppDelegate, logging: Bool)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure u add adcolonydelegate after appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

[According to the SDK](https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK/wiki/API-Details#configurewithappidzoneidsdelegatelogging), the `delegate` argument should be an `AdColonyDelegate` and not an `AppDelegate`. Your wrapping class (referenced using `self`) might not implement this protocol.

Moreover, the `appID` label needs to be removed. Indeed, in Swift, when calling a method, the first label is always omitted.